# mysql order by not included 0

Tags: mysql

i have query not working for order by

```
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE ParentID=139 AND `Position`!=0 AND 
        (
        (69.1 * (lattitude- 53.84787)) *
        (69.1 * (lattitude- 53.84787))
        ) + (
        (69.1 * (longitude- (-1.77684)) * COS(53.84787 / 57.3)) *
        (69.1 * (longitude- (-1.77684)) * COS(53.84787 / 57.3))
        ) <  POW(5, 2) ORDER BY `Position` ASC) 

        UNION 

        (SELECT * FROM products WHERE ParentID=139 AND `Position`=0 AND 
        (
        (69.1 * (lattitude- 53.84787)) *
        (69.1 * (lattitude- 53.84787))
        ) + (
        (69.1 * (longitude- (-1.77684)) * COS(53.84787 / 57.3)) *
        (69.1 * (longitude- (-1.77684)) * COS(53.84787 / 57.3))
        ) <  POW(5, 2) ORDER BY
        ((
                (69.1 * (lattitude- 53.84787)) *
                (69.1 * (lattitude- 53.84787))
        ) + (
        (69.1 * (longitude- (-1.77684)) * COS(53.84787 / 57.3)) *
        (69.1 * (longitude- (-1.77684)) * COS(53.84787 / 57.3))
        )),`Position` ASC )
```

it's not give me the order by position result.
i want that first the all result should come with position!=0 and then all 0 position records.

Comment: Are the results currently ordered at all?

Comment: do the two queries produce the correct sort order if you call them on their own, without the `UNION`?

Comment: add `ORDER BY Position = 0` at the end of the query.

Comment: ya, two queries produce the correct sort order if you call them on their own, without the UNION

Comment: ORDER BY Position = 0 gives same result. no change

Comment: @Kartik impossible :) Most likely you added this not at the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in using `ORDER BY` clauses in intermediate queries or subqueries. MySQL will not care to keep such order on the final result set.